# how to align the header to left in html in css?

Tags: html

i am trying to align the header to the left of the page.but it is aligned to the center of the page.how to align it to the center by using css? is there any css property to align the table header to the left of the page?

my code

```
<style type="text/css">

body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}


#gobutton {
    padding:5px 25px; 
    color:#0000ff;
    font-size:1.1em;
}

</style>
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h2>
                <img src="lock.jpg"  width="80" height="30"/>
                Login Form 
            </h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>  
                <form name="new" action=""  onsubmit="">
                    <tr>
                        <td> <p>User name:<p> </td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Password:<p></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td colspan="2" align="center">
                           <input id="gobutton" type="submit" value="Go!"/>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
               </form>
           </table>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not that tough, did you tried doing it? also, don't use tables for layout purposes

Comment: yeah i know.but i am just a beginner,so they told me to learn the layout with table first..

Comment: This html makes me cry. Tables for layout, ``align`` attribute which has been deprecated since a few versions, ``input``s without names...

Comment: @ashokkumar who are *they* ? *they* should be shot for giving you such bad advice.

Comment: @ashokkumar Don't go with the advices, always go for peer suggestions, so leave this right now, spend some time learning html and css positioning, and you will start making some good layouts soon

Comment: You can put the `H2` before the `<table>`, having said that your HTML is very old school, it's been about 20 years since tables have been used for tabular data exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align the table header to the left of the page, try using the css property

`text-align:left;`

Like this :

```
<h2 stlye="text-align:left;"><img src="lock.jpg"  width="80" height="30"/>Login Form</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you still want to use table, but here is the answer for this HTML

set h2 align to left

```
<td>
    <h2 style="text-align:left;">
        <img src="lock.jpg"  width="80" height="30"/>Login Form
    </h2>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
h2{
    text-align:left;
}

<h2 id="h2">
 <img src="lock.jpg"  width="80" height="30"/>Login Form 
 </h2>
```